# How to get value back from a web services in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, json

I am sending a URL and XML to a webservices, so that it will return me JSON about the result. I am here posting the request to the webservices how do I get the value from the webservices back. The value returned by the webservices is JSON. What should be the return type here and what should be returned to get the HTTP response status and body

```
public string HttpPostcredentials(string XML, string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XML);
        req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        req.ContentType = "application/xml";
        Stream PostData = req.GetRequestStream();
        PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        PostData.Close();            
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Empty `catch` clauses are the root of all evil.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Concat(serviceUrl, resourceUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;
if (request != null)
{
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.Method = "POST";
}    

byte[] requestBodyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XML);
request.ContentLength = requestBodyBytes.Length;
using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    postStream.Write(requestBodyBytes, 0, requestBodyBytes.Length);


if (request != null)
{
    var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        if (responseStream != null)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        responseMessage = response.StatusDescription;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Response from the HttpWebRequest

```
        WebResponse result = req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: And cast it to HttpWebResponse, so that you'll have access to StatusCode.